# How to show parenthesis in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<span>{`(${value})`}</span>
```

I am expecting (value), that is (5) in the browser, assuming 5 as value.

Comment: What is the issue? Your code shows `(5)` if `value` is `5`.

Comment: but is not showing (5), I am getting 5 instead the parenthesis is missing.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it with either with your code.  The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Please try and create a reproducible example, you can use a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) ([working example](https://jsfiddle.net/jm2acu39/))

Comment: thanks for everyone, I am looking at another part of the code and seeing the other part as output. sorry for wasting your time. cheers have a good day.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the problem. As you can see below, your version produces text with the parentheses, as expected. To reduce the clutter, I would suggest `<span>({value})</span>` instead, though.

```js
const App = ({}) => {
  const value = 5;
  return (
    <p>
      <span>{`(${value})`}</span><br />
      <span>({value})</span>
    </p>
  )
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Please see my edit and approve appropriately as this answer uses an extremely outdated React syntax unnecessarily.